# Wrong Wolfram alpha result on $nth$ derivative?

Tags: derivatives, wolfram-alpha

I'm working with this function

$$f(x)=\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-a}\right)^{-b}$$

and I would like to know the $nth$ derivative of $f(x)$. To this end, I ask *Wolfram alpha* about that given me the following result

$$f^{(n}(x)=\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-a}\right)^{-b-n} (1-b-n)_n$$

where $(x)_n$ means the Pochhammer symbol.  (See the link:   [Wolfram alpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B1%2F(x%2Bsqrt(x%5E2-a))%5Eb,%7Bx,n%7D%5D) )

It's easy compare  $n=1$ (for example) and one can observe that result is wrong.

Is there something wrong with my procedure?
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: You should report it to them (there is a feedback link at the bottom). It looks like you entered the formula correctly, because it shows the correct interpretation. But it looks like it just took the $n^{th}$ derivative of $t^{-b}$ with respect to $t$, then substituted $t = x + \sqrt{x^2 - a}$ instead of applying the chain rule.

Comment: I'm surprised !! Wolfram alpha send me the following _______

*Thank you for your feedback regarding Wolfram|Alpha. After review, our internal development group believes the output given is correct:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B1%2F(x%2Bsqrt(x%5E2-a))%5Eb,%7Bx,n%7D%5D

If you still disagree, please elaborate by providing source
links to the specific information that you are interested in seeing.

Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Best wishes*______How their development group can say that this is correct? 

Incredible !